# Why can't a reference, which is assigned to a child class, access the child class's members

Tags: java

```
class pract1 {

    String s="s1";
    public String getS()
    { 
        return s; 
    }
 } 
class pract  extends pract1{
    String a="s2";
    public String getS()    { 
        return a;
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        pract1 parent= new pract1();
        pract child= new pract();
        parent=child;
        System.out.println(parent.a); // syntax error it should be (parent.s);
        System.out.println(parent.getS());
    }
 }
```

Here i am assigning `child` to `parent`. Using the `parent` reference, I should be able to access the `a` field. However, that is giving a compile error. Why?

Comment: 'parent' (being of type pract1) has not knowledge of a variable named 'a'.  It will only have access to those parts of pract that are contained in pract1 (or, to put it another way, only have access to pract1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access a child class's instance variable from a parent class reference because the binding is at compile time (and during compile time it is very clear that 'a' is not part of pract1) unlike the overridden methods which are bound runtime i.e. dynamic binding

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mark it protected or public to be readable by your descendent.

e.g.

```
protected String s;
```

Comment: if you dont have a visibility declareation, you will be using the default visibility, which is visible to all classes in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Tried, does not seem to give any error and does exactly as shown in the snippet.

Prints out "s1" and then "s2"

although it is generally good practice to declare the variables visibility.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake transcribing the code.  Also, good practice is to declare *attributes* as `private`.  Variables that are not attributes cannot have a visibility modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the apparent type of the reference versus the actual type of the reference.

If you do this:

```
  pract1 p = new pract();
```

then the apparent type is "pract1". And the actual type is "pract"

The apparent type is known at compile time. That is, the compiler does type checking against the apparent type. So when you attempt to access members of the sub class, as far as the compiler is concerned the super class does not have those members so its an error.

This is necessary because a reference to pract1 may not necessarily refer to an instance of pract. The compiler takes no chances.

At run time however, the actual type is used.